# Do pre-loaded Windows apps get updated automatically without signing into the Windows store?

Tags: windows-10, windows-store

We are in an enterprise environment and have enabled the private store via GPO.  If you open the app store it will not open/load until you sign into your work account else you get an error.

Will default and OEM apps update automatically without a user signing in?

If no, is there a way to push store sign-ins automatically with user's domain creds?

Comment: I've seen Windows from a clean install downloading all of its additional apps so it happens at least once. I do not know if this is a one-off action or a continuous ongoing process. It might be that this is tied to the "Receive updates for other Microsoft Products" option you can find in Windows Update advanced settings.

Comment: I'll take a look.  I just don't know what the behavior is when using the private store since it forces a login unlike the default base install.